# Word for rhetorical style where different arguments get progressively weaker

Tags: single-word-requests, rhetoric

I'm looking for a word to describe the rhetorical style where one uses different arguments that are not additional, but rather get weaker and weaker. I'm not explaining it very well, so let me give an example.

If *Alice* argues that *X* is true because of *Y*, *Bob* might say:

1. *X is not true*.
2. *Even if X were true, it's irrelevant*
3. *Even if X were true and relevant, it doesn't speak in favour of Y*.

I'm quite sure I've seen a word to describe such a kind of reasoning, but it was a long time ago and I don't have a clue what it was (I'm not even 100% sure the word was in English). Is there a word to describe this?

Comment: Could be off-topic. If you can find a standard definition of the concept, perhaps a thesaurus might help.

Comment: How can I use a reference if I don't know what word to look for?

Comment: That's what a thesaurus is for. It's the reverse of a dictionary. Try phrases nearest to the idea and get the appropriate words.

Comment: If this is off-topic, then what is the [tag:single-word-requests] tag for?

Comment: If you can state/ explain clearly what is the concept you have in mind, we could find a one-word answer that defines the concept. I didn't say it is off-topic *per se*, else I would have voted to close.

Comment: Would it be fair to call this a form of rhetorical backpedaling?

Answer (score 10):

This might be a form of [*catacosmesis*](http://dailytrope.com/2011/06/08/catacosmesis-3/), which is the ordering of components (usually words, not arguments) from most to least important. It is the opposite of *climax* (rhetorically speaking), so perhaps you might refer to arguments arranged this way as *anticlimactic*.

But the structure you cite is more about stating an argument, then adding a condition that if that argument fails here is another argument, and so on. I might be tempted to call this an order of successive conditionals. It is certainly how lawyers proceed:

1. My client didn't commit the crime.
2. Even if he did commit it, the statute of limitations has run out.
3. Even if the statute of limitations hasn't run out, there were extenuating circumstances (e.g., he was temporarily insane, etc.).
4. And so on, until the judge tells the lawyer to shut up.

Note that these are not necessarily in descending order of importance. They are just a grab-bag of objections to an accusation, listed in a conditional sequence.

Hmm, now that I take into account the numbering, you might also call this [eutrepismus](http://dailytrope.com/2008/01/06/eutrepismus/).

Comment: One obvious downside to *catacosmesis* is that it's not even in OED (as I just discovered when looking for an "adjectival" form of the word!). On that basis, I don't think it would be a good idea to throw it into a conversation about "rhetorical devices" unless you were at least prepared to put it "in quotes".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It's a rhetorical term that exists in a number of sources. If a word isn't in the OED, does that mean it isn't an English word?

Comment: @FumbleFingers First, whyever would you need to look in a dictionary to realize that all Greek-derived *‑esis* nouns regularly go to *‑etic* adjectivally? That’s just how the morphology works. And secondly, historically the OED has intentionally omitted hundreds and probably thousands of words for any number of reasons; they have an article about this somewhere. So just because you do not find a word in the OED does not mean its use must be scare-quoted. Many technical terms, of which this is clearly one, are not there yet. As space concerns over print costs disappear, this may change.

Comment: @Robusto: I certainly don't mean to imply that only things in OED are valid "words". But it *is* pretty rare (I find only 47 instances in Google Books), and it does seem firmly rooted in the ordering of *words*, not arguments. You can make a case for it in OP's context, but I just think it's a pretty weak one (that being my weakest argument here, obviously! :)

Comment: @tchrist: Granted it's not necessarily significant that the word isn't in OED - the point is I didn't find the [obvious?] *catacosmetic* on Google, so I thought I'd look in OED to see an example of usage. At which point I discovered that even the noun form wasn't there, which is why I ended up posting my own answer. I hadn't noticed at the time that Robusto had also offered *anticlimactic* - if I *had*, I wouldn't have bothered with my own answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: So you hadn't even bothered to read to the end of my first paragraph before posting a critique of it?

Comment: @Robusto: Well, probably not exactly the way you're thinking. I'd already started writing my answer when the message popped up to say there was another answer. I didn't know the word *catacosmesis*, but because I assumed OP was looking for an adjective, I Googled *catacosmetic* and got nothing. So I went back and completed my answer before reading the rest of your text. I would have deleted my answer then, if it hadn't been for the fact that I then didn't find *catacosmesis* in OED. But I'd certainly read all your text by the time I posted my comment, and decided to leave my own answer in.

Comment: You don't seem to have accounted for the successive retraction of propositions, which is the main point. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Kris: Yes. Apparently you didn't read my answer at all.

Comment: At least, most of ELU users did. Your example is in no way related to the OP's: "successive retraction of propositions" -- once again.

Comment: @Kris: You don't know what you're talking about. Your comment on the OP's question asks for "a standard definition of the concept," so by your own admission you don't even understand what is being asked. Now you call it a "successive retraction of propositions," which is nonsense because nothing is being retracted, only added to. No one else mentions this in their responses, but you don't give them tart, censorious comments and down votes. You seem to want to be a little flea on my back for some reason I do not fathom, so go ahead: be that small.

Comment: @Robusto It's not very nice to see someone take it personally and react this way. (**I strictly avoid personal remarks**, However: The someone who up voted this last comment of yours may find favor with you but that does not mean it's correct or justified.) "No one else mentions this:" With this atmosphere prevailing, it would be no surprise that no one would so much as care to speak up and say anything that may invite unwarranted personal remarks. Sorry that it hurts some people, but I stand by what I said. see: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/93612/14666

Comment: No, I'm not hurt. The bite of a flea will not bring me down. Nor will your flea-bite down votes. It is just something of a puzzle why you bear me such an animus. Not an interesting puzzle, mind you, but a puzzle nonetheless.

Answer (score 7):

Your example is known in law as an [alternative pleading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_pleading), and apparently Freud called it [kettle logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettle_logic), as in, "Your kettle was fine when I returned it, and it was already broken when I borrowed it, and I never borrowed it."

Comment: I think what I actually meant was kettle logic, but my original example was not a good one.

Comment: +1 Correct. The OP has confirmed that his idea was *this* . No other answer has considered the basic logic of the case, that of successively retracting, revising and/or denying.

Answer (score 3):

Robusto gave a dailytrope.com link that defines *[catacosmesis](http://dailytrope.com/2011/06/08/catacosmesis-3/)* as

> Ordering words from greatest to least in dignity, or in correct order of time.

That definition appears to be copied from [rhetoric.byu.edu](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/c/catacosmesis.htm).  Somewhat more useful information is given by Henry Peachum, in the [*Schemas* section of his 1593 book](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.03.0096%3Apart%3DSchemates+Rhetorical%3Asubpart%3DThe+second+order%3Asection%3DFigures+of+Permission%3Asubsection%3DCatacosmesis) ***The Garden of Eloquence***:

> Catacosmesis, in Latine ordo, is a meete placing of words among themselves, wherof there be two kinds, the one when the worthiest word is set first, which order is naturall, as when we say: God and man, men and women, Sun and moone, life and death. And also when that is first told that was first done, which is necessary and seemly. ...
>   The use of this first kind of order, doth most properly serve to the propertie and elegancy of speech, and due observation of nature and dignitie: which forme is well represented in the civil and solemne customs of nations, where the worthiest person are alwaies first named and highest [placed].
>   The grace and comelinesse of this order is often diminished, and much blemished through want of discretion, or by rashnesse of the speaker, putting the lesse worthie, before the more worthy, ...

In short, the rhetorical form catacosmesis consists of placing words in proper order (when that proper order is most important first, or highest ranking first) to strengthen a passage.  Catacosmesis is a positive term.  Listing the best reasons first appears to be an example of catacosmesis.  (As FumbleFingers points out, either arranging arguments to rise to a climax, or to fall from one in anticlimax, is rhetorically more effective than a pyramidal arrangement.)

One also finds the technique described as a “Arson, Murder, And Jaywalking” trope.  [TVtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ArsonMurderAndJaywalking/Literature) offers numerous examples, including:

> • Juvenal (second century A.D.) uses this now and then in his satires. Most of the time his examples actually escalate (adultery, murder, murder of close relations) but now and then he throws in this trope, as in listing the dangers of living in Rome as “conflagrations, collapsing buildings, poets reciting in the month of August”.
>   • In her non-fiction book, *Stiff: The Curious Lives of Human Cadavers*, Mary Roach describes her experience at a mortuary college embalming lab. Anyone who enters the blood splash area has to wear plastic and latex to protect against HIV, hepatitis, and stains on your shirt.

Comment: "Forty years of darkness! Earthquakes, volcanoes...
The dead rising from the grave!
Human sacrifice, dogs and cats living together..."

Answer (score 1):

It's worth pointing out first of all that *"When citing multiple arguments, classical rhetoric recommends placing the strongest argument **last**"* [(p.55 in that pdf link)](http://www.rabbinics.org/Hidary_AJSReview%20-%20Rhetoric.pdf).

This "classical" sequence is largely based on the idea that ordinary people remember the last argument most clearly, so for maximum effect it should be the strongest one. Rhetoric is much concerned with using devices/tricks to  artificially sway the audience, so obviously a skilled professional would soon get used to the idea of inverting his "natural" argument sequence.

Thus OP's context is effectively "non-standard" rhetoric. But I think there's no doubt it's the format most likely to be used by ordinary people, since it reflects the way we normally think. Here's the best summary of the position I can find...

> “Be aware that people will remember what you say first (the primary principle) and what you say last (the recency principle). In light of this, it is logical that arranging your arguments either from weakest to strongest (climax) or from *strongest to weakest (anticlimax)* would be more effective than placing your best points in the middle (pyramidal)”

In light of that from [The Speakers Handbook](http://www.sfu.ca/personal/dmirhady/arrangement.pdf), Sprague and Stuart, I suggest **aniticlimactic**.

Comment: so maybe the word the OP wants is 'bad rhetoric'.

Comment: @Mitch: I didn't want to go that far, which is why I tentatively put up "non-standard". But when I Google **rhetoric "strongest to weakest" arguments**, it reports only 33,800 results - as opposed to 17,800,000 for the more "conventional" **rhetoric "weakest to strongest" arguments**. So perhaps you're right!

Answer (score 0):

While I realise that this is a [single-word-request](/questions/tagged/single-word-request), you might be thinking of [reductio ad absurdum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum):

> Reductio ad absurdum (Latin: "**reduction to absurdity**") is a common form of argument which seeks to demonstrate that a statement is true by showing that a false, untenable, or absurd result follows from its denial, or in turn to demonstrate that a statement is false by showing that a false, untenable, or absurd result follows from its acceptance.

> The "absurd" conclusion of a reductio ad absurdum argument can take a range of forms:
>
> - Rocks have weight, otherwise we would see them floating in the air.
> - Society must have laws, otherwise there would be chaos.
> - There is no smallest positive rational number, because if there were, it could be divided by two to get a smaller one.

Comment: A reductio ad absurdum is something completely different from what I mean. Maybe I didn't explain clearly enough what I meant.

Comment: @gerrit Fair enough. I thought that the "reduction" to "absurdity" might have correlated to "progressively" and "weaker".

Comment: Actually, I think if it means anything at all to talk about the "sequence of arguments" in a *reductio ad absurdum* presentation, you'd probably have to say the ***last*** argument is overwhelmingly the most powerful one, since that's the point at which it becomes clear the proposition [being argued *against*] is completely untenable!